# How to remove files from bitbucket repository?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I've accidentally added and committed several large files to a repository and would like to remove them so I don't hit Bitbucket's repo limit. Is there a way to delete them from history?

Comment: I changed the title to clarify, but maybe it was I who misunderstood; have the changes been pushed to bitbucket? (If not, it's easy to recover with `hg strip`)

Comment: @alexis they have not been pushed but they were committed with changes to other files I'd like to keep.